# I want to pick all workitem from TFS using .wiq file,But getting errors while doing so

Tags: powershell-ise

Below is piece of code.

{
   # Load required assemblies
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client")
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client")

```
# Wiq Path
$WiqPath = $PSScriptRoot+"\"+$wiqFile

try
{
    # Get TFS server and query from WIQ file
    [xml]$WiqlXML = Get-Content $WiqPath
    [String]$TFSservername = $WiqlXML | % {$_.WorkItemQuery.TeamFoundationServer} 
    [String]$queryString = $WiqlXML | % {$_.WorkItemQuery.Wiql}

    Write-Host "TFS path is: " $TFSservername "`r`n"


    $teamProjectCollection = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]::GetTeamProjectCollection($TFSservername)

    # Get workitem collection from TFS Project
    $ws = $teamProjectCollection.GetService([type][Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore])

    # If user has passed explicitly Ids
    if($workItemIds)
    {                
          $workIs = $workItemIds.Split(',')
          # collection of workitem objects
          $wis = @()
          foreach($wi in $workIs)
          {                      
              $wis += $ws.getworkitem($wi)                
          }      

    }
    # If user hasn't passed Ids, taking Workitem Ids from wiqFile
    else
    {
      $wis = $ws.Query($queryString)


    }
    # Pass Default credentials. Make sure whoever is running script, have access on TFS project
    [Net.WebClient] $request =  New-Object Net.WebClient
    $request.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
}
```

Exception details :-

Caught an exception:
Exception Type: System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException
Exception Message: Exception calling "Query" with "1" argument(s): "The specified variable does not exist. The error is caused by «@project»."

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. As a workaround, I replaced the @project field with the project name from Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Project-object. In your case you should also add the project name to WIQ file. Otherwise if the project name is constant, you could just replace it with your project name:

```
    $projectName = "MyTfsProject"
    $queryString = $queryString -replace "@project", ("'{0}'" -f $projectName)
```